# Some Apostrophes showing as â?T in HTML Emails

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm using ASP Classic/VBScript to send emails using CDO.Message object. It appears that the single quote or apostrophe character ’ (as opposed to the standard character ') shows up in the recipients email as: â?T

Where is the problem and what is the best way to resolve this? I actually tried running a replace to change all ’ to ' but it appears that didn't work.

I guess I'm really not even sure what the difference is between these two different characters, and why some sites, like Microsoft for example, use ’.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer rather than an edit to your question. Then accept your own answer. This will mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indeed was a problem of character encoding. The solution was to put two lines of code in the web page that contains my form. I actually opted to add these lines of code to the top of my Global include file which I named inc_globals.asp. This file appears at the top of every page. Here's the code that fixed the problem:

```
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
```

As a matter of documentation, here's a post that was helpful in solving this case:
http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.inetserver.asp.general/browse_thread/thread/b79e6b95e24ef0fe/a25c643aaf12770d

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheAskObamaTweetWasGarbledOnScreenKnowYourUTF8UnicodeASCIIAndANSIDecodingMrPresident.aspx

all the info you could need on character encoding.

Comment: You're answer is fundamentally correct but it doesn't answer one of my original questions: "what is the best way to resolve this?"

Comment: @HK1 Then you could upvote him for providing a helpful answer while not accepting as the best one...

Comment: @HK1, sorry about that, the best way is to not use SmartQuotes, but if for some reason you must then as you have found you must specify the encoding that you are using so that the client knows how to interpret the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct character encoding on `.BodyPart.Charset` of your `CDO.Message` object.

Most likely you need to set it to `"utf-8"` as [the default appears to be `"us-ascii"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526296%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx).

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it made no difference. I also tried BodyPart.ContentTransferEncoding = "quoted-printable" and that didn't help either. I'm baffled as to why your suggestion didn't work. I'm finding lots of other references using Google to changing .BodyPart.Charset as you suggested.

Comment: @HK1 Do you know what charset the string you're adding to the body part is?  If it's just a default string object it might be "utf-16".  You may also need to set the [`urn:schemas:mailheader:content-transfer-encoding` in the header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms875081%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx) to match whatever you're sending as.

Answer (score 0):

Mails are written in HTML format. Have you tried using HTML Entities? For your apostrophe, it should be `&#39;`.

In VB :

```
Replace mailBody, "'", "&#39;"
```